# Every natural number can be written in form of $3a+5b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \left\{ 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm5,\pm6,...\right\}$
prove that every natural number can be written in form of $3a+5b$
like : $$1=5\times2-3\times3\\2=5\times1-3\times1\\3=5\times0+3\times1\\4=5\times2-3\times2\\ \cdots$$
we can prove it by induction 
$$n \in \left\{1,2,3,4,5,...\right\} \\ a,b \in \left\{ 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm5,\pm6,...\right\}\\
p(1): 1=5\times2-3\times 3=10-9\\$$ $$p(k): k=3\times a+5\times b \\$$ $$p(k+1): k+1=3\times a'+5\times b'\\ \to k+1=3\times a+5\times b+5\times2-3\times 3\\k+1=3\times(a-3)+5\times(b+2)  \space \checkmark$$ $$\bf "now"$$ my question is ... how prove it without induction ?
    any idea, hint or answer will be appreciated.

Comment: See [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can find $a,b$ such that $3a+5b=1$ then every integer $n$ will be

$$ n=1\cdot n=(3a+5b)\cdot n=3(an)+5(bn). $$

Comment: This is like a trivial concepts but ...very cute . thanks .Is there more ideas ?

Comment: @Khosrotash What?

Comment: @Khosrotash The idea behind it is that $3,5$ are coprime, so there exist integers $a,b$ such that $3a+5b=1$. If that doesn't sound familiar, see for example [Two Properties of Greatest Common Divisor](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/gcd.shtml). You could prove the very same way that every integer can be written as $2a+3b$, or $7a+19b$, or...

Comment: I understand your method . Thank you very much . After that I asked for new ideas more . I do apologize If you became angry !

Comment: Now I remember form high school ! $$ax+by=m \\ (x,y)|m \\ 3a+5b=n \to (3,5)|n , (3,5)=1|n$$ for all $n$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: @Khosrotash That's correct, but only proves the reverse (easy) implication. What you need is that if $(3,5)=1$ then there exist $a,b$ such that $3a+5b=1$. That's usually derived from the [Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), and it is a well known property of the $\gcd$.